# Знак коммента в начале JS-скриптов

Tags: javascript, html

Вопрос чисто теоретический.

Часто встречаю в чужих скриптах знак `<!--` в начале. Приведу кусочек кода для примера (это счетчик LiveInternet)

```
<script>
<!--
document.write("<a href='//www.liveinternet.ru/click' ...
</script>
```

Валидатор ругается на незакрытый знак, но скрипт предлагается именно в таком виде, хотя без `<!--` все тоже прекрасно работает (вроде бы =)

Интересует зачем это в коде и как его сделать валидным?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот что пишут об этом в [учебнике](https://learn.javascript.ru/hello-world):

> **Комментарии до и после скриптов**
>
> В совсем старых руководствах и книгах
>   иногда рекомендуют использовать HTML-комментарии внутри SCRIPT, чтобы
>   спрятать Javascript от браузеров, которые не поддерживают его.
>
> Выглядит это примерно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
... //--></script>
```

> Браузер, для которого предназначались такие трюки, очень старый Netscape, давно умер. Поэтому в этих комментариях
>   нет нужды.
>
> Итак, для вставки скрипта мы просто пишем `<script>`, без дополнительных
>   атрибутов и комментариев.

Answer (score 2):

Это делается если вдруг браузер не поддерживает javascript. Например я зашел на твой сайт и у меня выключен javascript и весь код показываю в html, что не круто. Но сейчас это уже не актуально.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы [скрыть код скрипта](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#idx-user_agent) от старых браузеров. Если код не закомментировать, они могут показать его как обычный текст.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
<!--  to hide script contents from old browsers

// end hiding contents from old browsers  -->
</SCRIPT>
```

Движок скрипта проигнорирует первую строку, начинающуюся с `<!--`. А конец HTML-комментария от него прячут, поставив в начале строки две косые черты.